# How can I have a double value using Math.DivRem()?

Tags: c#, parsing, modulo

I can't show the double values in C#

```
Math.DivRem(double money, int number, out int remain);
```

Comment: You want an integer remainder from dividing one double by another? whut?

Comment: Are you looking for [Math.IEEERemainder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ieeeremainder)?

Comment: I fixed the code. I need to show a as double because I will operate a double with an integer Math.Round((money / nunber) + remain) but inside DivRem() money will show an error because must work with an integer type

Comment: so 8.4 divided by 2.2 is what.. 3 remainder 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Tuple<int, double> DivRem(double left, double right)
{
    return Tuple.Create((int)Math.Floor(left / right), left % right);
}
```

Use `Math.Floor` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` since the latter will round *up* to the nearest even integer.

Answer (score -1):

[Math.DivRem Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-5.0) is only compatible with Int64 and Int32, which means you can't use double, float or any numeric data type with decimals.

Depending on what you are looking for, this is two other methods of getting the quotient and remainder of your doubles:

```
double a = 20.1;
double b = 4.93;

double remainder = a % b; // Returns 0.380...
double quotient = a / b; // Returns 4,077...
```

If you want to make your remainder or quotient to an **int**, just use

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(quotient); // Returns 4
```

Or to make it more efficient

```
int result = ConvertToInt32(a / b); // Returns 4
```

**EDIT**

One workaround to use Math.DivRem with "doubles", are by multiplying both sides with a constant, for example 100 000. After getting the remainder, divide it with the constant.

```
double money = 5.515;
int number = 2;
int constant = 100000;

Math.DivRem(Convert.ToInt32(money * constant), number * constant, out int remain); 
// Divides 551500 with 200000
// remain = 151500

// For double
double d = (double) remain / (double) constant; // Return 1,515

// For int
remain /= constant; // Return 1
```

**DOUBLE EDIT**

Use this instead of `Math.DivRem()` when dealing with doubles and ints combined.

```
double money = 12.15;
int number = 5;
double remainder = money % number; // Return 2,15...
int remainder = (int)(money % number); // Return 2
```

Comment: We don't need you to label every edit with a header, btw

Comment: Thanks alot Robin. I will try this tomorrow and tell you if it worked for me.

Comment: One bug, Convert.ToInt32() rounds to the nearest even number, for example 5.5 => 6.